# Get HTML Element value from URL

Tags: c#, html, uwp, webbrowser-control

**How can i get the XHtml code in c#?**

I'm loading the web page `myweb.Source = new Uri(@"https://" + @urlstring.Text);`

and i'm saving the html  in string

```
WebClient a = new WebClient();
byte[] data = a.DownloadData(myweb.Source.ToString());
string ab = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

now i'm looking for the video Url path

```
string id = "";
int index = ab.IndexOf("<video")
int indexe = ab.IndexOf("</video>");
for (int i = index; i <= indexe + 100; i++)
   {
       id += ab[i];
   }
```

the result is

```
<video class="js-select-menu-off vjs-video"
                data-account="3695997568001"
                data-player="SyDW1dJDG"
                data-embed="default"
                data-video-id=""
                controls></video>
<div class="playback-speed-popover popover dark">
    <div class="inner-popover">
```

but what i want is this :

```
<video class="vjs-tech" data-account="3695997568001" 
data-player="SyDW1dJDG" data-embed="default" 
data-video-id="" id="vjs_video_3_html5_api"
poster="blablabla" src="https://hous......"></video>
```

how can i get the src from the web page ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using .NET Core In My Example With Visual Studio Code. Use to following to install HtmlAgilityPack:

```
dotnet add package HtmlAgilityPack --version 1.11.16
```

The code below is how i would solve for it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        var content = client.GetStringAsync(@"https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp").Result;
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(content);            
        var  videos = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("video").FirstOrDefault().Attributes["src"].Value;            
    }
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/7tDP6nB i have the same error its loding the html and i need to load XHtml for this https://ibb.co/dJk4996

Comment: var  videos = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("video").FirstOrDefault().Attributes["src"].Value;

Comment: you have the wrong tag in the screenshot above if you want the value from the src attribute. try it with the line i supplied above.

Comment: are you logged in when you are inspecting the web page? I'm wondering if html elements get added when you login to the website. I only see this html markup on the link provided on the other answer             <div class="video-player-module">
                <video class="js-select-menu-off vjs-video"
                    data-account="3695997568001"
                    data-player="SyDW1dJDG"
                    data-embed="default"
                    data-video-id=""
                    controls></video>

Comment: also after login i still cant see the src but i see the video in the app

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net) with XPath.

Paste below code to run in here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vtwi7g

```
// @nuget: HtmlAgilityPack

using System;
using System.Xml;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var html = @"https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp";

        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

        var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);

        var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//video");

        Console.WriteLine("Node Name: " + node.Name + "\n" + node.OuterHtml + "\n Node id is: " + node.Attributes["id"].Value);     
    }
}
```

The result will be:

```
Node Name: video
<video id="video1" style="width:600px;max-width:100%;" controls="">
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
 Node id is: video1
```

In your case, you just change the attribute to poster instead of id. For more information, check out this document https://html-agility-pack.net/documentation

Comment: its return null :(

Comment: You didn't change the attribute "id" in my sample to "poster" yet. It's null may be the "id" is not exist. Can you post your url so I can check it?

Comment: i'm working on app for myself to download video's from skillshare this the URL that i'm trying to asses https://www.skillshare.com/classes/FL-Studio-Learn-Music-Production-In-FL-Studio-In-A-Day/1196029070/projects

Comment: i deleted the id and it's the same resalt that i have https://ibb.co/bPbtrPD

Comment: the poster is with in the <video > so its dont have source

Comment: Actually it doesn't have "poster" attribute inside video tag: view-source:https://www.skillshare.com/classes/FL-Studio-Learn-Music-Production-In-FL-Studio-In-A-Day/1196029070 .  Where is the url that you expected?

Comment: @rynexakil so now can you get it?

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Node Name: " + node.Name + "\n" + node.OuterHtml }=> 
     <video class="js-select-menu-off vjs-video" data-account="3695997568001" data-player="SyDW1dJDG" data-embed="default" data-video-id="" controls=""></video>      why its dont have the src ?

Comment: @rynexakil Ok after I inspected them I detected that the poster is using another request then add it by js. The request required logged account and will be expired after a while: https://edge.api.brightcove.com/playback/v1/accounts/3695997568001/videos/5968709441001

Comment: So basically it seems complicated to get the poster https://cf-images.us-east-1.prod.boltdns.net/v1/jit/3695997568001/735b82d7-023e-42d0-9a26-5f7780ea41e9/main/1280x720/48s700ms/match/image.jpg

Comment: I suggest you use thumbnail in the main page meta tag  https://static.skillshare.com/uploads/video/thumbnails/5606f622b3dfd026c4d1d9b1167e222a/original

Comment: this the image , i want the video and the xpath is  //*[@id="vjs_video_3_html5_api"]

Comment: Download the video is out of the topic scope. I just suggest you lookup the http request https://edge.api.brightcove.com/playback/v1/accounts/3695997568001/videos/5968709441001 => the response is json content which included video link (find keyword "source"), it also complicated with token security to limit watch times from them. The video file is .m3u8 file, so you need the player to play them.